# How can know which value I have in a form (to display something if this value is what is want)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML Code:

```
<form>
  <select name="city" id="city">
    <option class="orase" value="0">Choose City</option>
    <option class="orase" value="1">Berlin</option>
    <option class="orase" value="2">Prague</option>
    <option class="orase" value="3">London</option>
    <input type="submit" name="srch1" id="srch1" value="Display"/>
  </select>
</form>
```

and I want to display something only when the city is Berlin and the value is submited (the button is pressed). But this javascript code is not working.

```
var city = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
var button = document.getElementById("srch1");
button.attachEvent("onsubmit", getCity());
var getCity = function () {
if (city.innerHTML === "Berlin") {
  document.write("You are in Berlin");
  }
}
```

Comment: put then the page will submit and the page will refresh...  you sure you want a `submit` button?

Comment: also, onsubmit is an event of a form not a button

Comment: It's now imporant which type has the input. If this type is "button" is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <select name="city" id="city">
    <option class="orase" value="0">Choose City</option>
    <option class="orase" value="1">Berlin</option>
    <option class="orase" value="2">Prague</option>
    <option class="orase" value="3">London</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" name="srch1" id="srch1">Display</button>
</form>
```

And JS:

```
var city = document.getElementById("city");
var button = document.getElementById("srch1");
var getCity = function () {
  if (city.value === "1") {
    document.body.innerHTML += "You are in Berlin";
  }
};
button.addEventListener("click", getCity);
```

Some changes:

- Used `button` instead `input` to prevent immediate submiiting and
  reloading of page. Also pulled it out from `select`.
- `city` retrieved with `getElementById()`, `getElementsByClassName()`
  returns an HTMLCollection, which is an array-like object containing
  all elements with a given class name.
- When you assign a function to a variable, it's not hoisted, hence
  moved the function above the expression, which refers it. Alternatively
  you can remove the `var` and declare the function: `function getCity () {...}`
- Checked `value` of `select` element, `innerHTML` would just contain
  the HTML for `option` elements.
- `document.write()` implicitely opens a new document, and all the
  content of the old-one is gone. Used simple `innerHTML` instead.
- Used `addEventListener()` instead of `attachEvent()`. The latter
  works only in IE<11. `addEventListener` works from IE9 on, and in all modern browsers. Notice the `click` listener and fixed second
  argument, just a function name, not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use jQuery, this works:

```
$("#city").change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var city = $("#city option:selected").text();
    if ( city == "Berlin" ) {
       alert("You are in Berlin");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8GMvE/

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option class="orase" value="0">Choose City</option>
    <option class="orase" value="1">Berlin</option>
    <option class="orase" value="2">Prague</option>
    <option class="orase" value="3">London</option>
  </select>

var a = document.getElementById("city");
a.onchange = function(e){
    var index = a.selectedIndex;
    alert("You are in " + a[index].innerHTML);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your input:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="displaySomething()" value="Display"/>
```

Then, in your `<script>`

```
function displaySomething()
{
 if(document.getElementById("city").options[document.getElementById("city").selectedIndex].value==1)
{
//Berlin selected!
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <select name="city" id="city">
    <option class="orase" value="0">Choose City</option>
    <option class="orase" value="1">Berlin</option>
    <option class="orase" value="2">Prague</option>
    <option class="orase" value="3">London</option>
    <input type="button" name="srch1" id="srch1" value="Display" onclick="f1();" />
  </select>
</form>


function f1() 
{
    if ( document.getElementById("city").value == 1) // value 1 is for Berlin
    {
        alert("do something in this block");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5dBT/1/)

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option class="orase" value="0">Choose City</option>
    <option class="orase" value="1">Berlin</option>
    <option class="orase" value="2">Prague</option>
    <option class="orase" value="3">London</option>
    <input type="submit" name="srch1" id="srch1" value="Display" onclick="eval()" />
</select>
<script>
    var city;

    function eval() {
        city = document.getElementById("city").value;
        alert(city);
        if (city == "1") {
            alert('you are in Berlin');
        }
    }
</script>
```

So a couple of things to note here, I'm using document.getElementById("city") because it's your select object which is holding the value when you click submit.  Also I added a function which is performed after you click the submit.  You want to make sure you grab the value of city after that time; instead of like you have it which will grab it's value on JS load (should be undefined at that point).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the simple and easy Jquery way.
lets give youre form an id `<form id='myForm'>` then use the following 
jquery code-

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    selected = $("#city option:selected").text();
    if(selected == "Berlin"){
        alert("your city is Berlin");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

this way it would fire the if statement only after the submit and not on the select change.